# The suspended cat clavicle

Tags: anatomy, vertebrates

I know the clavicle of the cat floats freely as opposed to be attached as in humans. This is supposed to allow them to be able to squeeze through spaces, according to a quick google search. But how does that allow them to move through tight spaces in comparison with humans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I learned from my comp vert anatomy class, the clavicle does not articulate with other skeletal elements, thus allowing the scapulae to retract further along with the forelimbs

Comment: Can you add a reference to your answer?